# MySQL Foreign key error 1215, even though both colums are of the same type and are NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Parent table `team_entrant`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `team_entrant` (
  `entrant_number` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `qualifying_position` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `qualifying_time` time(3) NOT NULL,
  `grid_position` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `best_race_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `final_position` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dnf_reason` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `competition_year` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entrant_number`),
  KEY `fk_team_entrant_team1_idx` (`team_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_team_entrant_team1` FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`) REFERENCES `team` (`team_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Child table/Associative table `entrant_drivers`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entrant_drivers` (
  `entrant_number` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `competition_year` date NOT NULL,
  `driver_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entrant_number`,`competition_year`,`driver_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ed_entrant_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`entrant_number`) REFERENCES `team_entrant` (`entrant_number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

At the time the team_entrant column `competition_year` did not exist.

**HeidiSQL refuses to execute the following code:**

```
ALTER table entrant_drivers ADD CONSTRAINT ed_comp_year_fk FOREIGN KEY (competition_year) REFERENCES team_entrant(competition_year);
```

**SQL Error (1215): Cannot add foreign key constraint**

Extraneous table, `driver` involved with the associative table:

```
-- Dumping structure for table 99_lemans_db1.driver
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `driver` (
  `driver_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `driver_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `driver_nationality` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `driver_birth_day` date NOT NULL,
  `driver_best_previous_finish_class` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `driver_best_previous_finish_position` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team_entrant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`driver_id`,`team_entrant_id`),
  KEY `fk_driver_team_entrant1_idx` (`team_entrant_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent column must be designated as an index/primary key.

team_entrant is supposed to be made up of the composite primary keys (entrant number, competition year).